# How to pack and unpack using ctypes (Structure <-> str)

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

This might be a silly question but I couldn't find a good answer in the docs or anywhere.

If I use **struct** to define a binary structure, the struct has 2 symmetrical methods for serialization and deserialization (pack and unpack) but it seems **ctypes** doesn't have a straightforward way to do this. Here's my solution, which feels wrong:

```
from ctypes import *

class Example(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("index", c_int),
        ("counter", c_int),
        ]

def Pack(ctype_instance):
    buf = string_at(byref(ctype_instance), sizeof(ctype_instance))
    return buf

def Unpack(ctype, buf):
    cstring = create_string_buffer(buf)
    ctype_instance = cast(pointer(cstring), POINTER(ctype)).contents
    return ctype_instance

if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = Example(12, 13)
    buf = Pack(e)
    e2 = Unpack(Example, buf)
    assert(e.index == e2.index)
    assert(e.counter == e2.counter)
    # note: for some reason e == e2 is False...
```

Comment: That looks about right to me. ctypes is not for serialization, so the fact that you can do it in 7 lines of code seems pretty good actually.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[The PythonInfo wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ctypes) has a solution for this.

> FAQ: How do I copy bytes to Python from a ctypes.Structure?
>
> ```
> def send(self):
>     return buffer(self)[:]
> ```
>
> FAQ: How do I copy bytes to a ctypes.Structure from Python?
>
> ```
> def receiveSome(self, bytes):
>     fit = min(len(bytes), ctypes.sizeof(self))
>     ctypes.memmove(ctypes.addressof(self), bytes, fit)
> ```

Their `send` is the (more-or-less) equivalent of `pack`, and `receiveSome` is sort of a `pack_into`.  If you have a "safe" situation where you're unpacking into a struct of the same type as the original, you can one-line it like  `memmove(addressof(y), buffer(x)[:], sizeof(y))` to copy `x` into `y`.  Of course, you'll probably have a variable as the second argument, rather than a literal packing of `x`.

Comment: I tested this solution and it works as well. What was more important to me was that you found an official python.org entity (the FAQ in the wiki is good enough) state that hacking it is the way to go. I just felt as though these 2 functions/methods had to be somewhere in ctypes.py already so hacking it using pointers seemed very unpythonic. I know some people say ctypes isn't built for serializing etc, but I like the ctypes OOP-ness a lot more than the perl-ish struct module.

Comment: What about Python3 which doesn't have `buffer`? If you try to simply replace it with `memoryview`, you'll get `TypeError: invalid indexing of 0-dim memory`

Comment: In Python3 you can use `bytes(self)` to extract the structure bytes.

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at this link on binary i/o in python:

http://www.dabeaz.com/blog/2009/08/python-binary-io-handling.html

Based on this you can simply write the following to read from a buffer (not just files):

```
g = open("foo","rb")
q = Example()
g.readinto(q)
```

To write is simply:

```
g.write(q)
```

The same for using sockets:

```
s.send(q)
```

and

```
s.recv_into(q)
```

I did some testing with pack/unpack and ctypes and this approach is the fastest except for writing straight in C

Comment: In 2.6+, a more generic `pack` is just `bytearray(q)`, which also uses the buffer protocol. For generic unpacking 2.6 also added, for example, `Example.from_buffer(buf)` if `buf` is mutable, else `Example.from_buffer_copy(buf)`.

Answer (score 13):

Tested on Python3

```
e = Example(12, 13)
serialized = bytes(e)
deserialized = Example.from_buffer_copy(serialized)
```

Answer (score 0):

see also the [kaitai](http://doc.kaitai.io/lang_python.html) binary parsing framework

> [Kaitai Struct](http://kaitai.io/#what-is-it) is a declarative language used to describe various binary data structures

example: [sqlite3.py](https://github.com/trailofbits/polyfile/blob/master/polyfile/kaitai/parsers/sqlite3.py) generated from [sqlite3.ksy](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/master/database/sqlite3.ksy)

```py
# sqlite3.py was generated by
# kaitai-struct-compiler -t python --python-package . sqlite3.ksy
from . import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.Sqlite3.from_file("some_database.db")

print(f"page size: {db.len_page} bytes")
print(f"db size: {db.num_pages} pages", )
```