# Get the binary representation of a ctypes Structure in Python

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I want to encode a message...This is the message that i have generated

```
from ctypes import memmove, addressof, Structure, c_uint16,c_bool

class AC(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("UARFCN",  c_uint16),
                 ("ValidUARFCN", c_bool ),("PassiveActivationTime", c_uint16) ]

    def __init__(self , UARFCN ,ValidUARFCN , PassiveActivationTime):
            self.UARFCN                 =    UARFCN
            self.ValidUARFCN            =    True
            self.PassiveActivationTime  =    PassiveActivationTime

    def __str__(self):
        s = "AC"
        s += "UARFCN:"  + str(self.UARFCN)
        s += "ValidUARFCN"  + str(self.ValidUARFCN)
        s += "PassiveActivationTime"  +str(self.PassiveActivationTime)
        return s

class ABCD(AC):
        a1 = AC( 0xADFC , True , 2)
        a2 = AC( 13 , False ,5)
        print a1
        print a2
```

I want to encode it and then store it in a variable.....So how can i do it???

Comment: What do you mean by "encode it"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want. But if it's what I'm guessing you could use `from hashlib import md5` and  `md5(String_here).hexdigest()`

Comment: Like if i have to send this msg to a receiver i will send it in an encoded form....

Comment: What is the "it" you're trying to encode?

Comment: So you mean you want to encrypt it, or what? Encode can mean anything, from "encode in ASCII" or "encode in unicode" or even "encode in compressed format". Encrypting, on the other hand, also requires sending the "key" that wil decrypt your message on the other end.

Comment: You haven't specified what the message is.

Comment: I have specified the things that i have printed...what if i have to send it an encoded form....

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by encoded: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code

Comment: @machine He means send it as it is represented in memory. That's what `pack` (`struct.pack`) meant in his first comment.

Comment: @machine: i dnt knw y r u nt getting what i am trying 2 say..its quite clear....agf has also mentioned it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C structures, all you have to do to write it to a file is open the file, then do

```
fileobj.write(my_c_structure).
```

Then you can reload it by opening the file and doing

```
my_c_structure = MyCStructure()
fileobj.readinto(my_c_structure)
```

All you need is to make your `__init__` arguments optional. See [this post on Binary IO](http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2009/08/python-binary-io-handling.html). It explains how to send `Structure` over sockets or with `multiprocessing` Listeners.

To save it in a string / bytes just do

```
from io import BytesIO # Or StringIO on old Pythons, they are the same
fakefile = BytesIO()
fakefile.write(my_c_structure)
my_encoded_c_struct = fakefile.getvalue()
```

Then read it back out with

```
from io import BytesIO # Or StringIO on old Pythons, they are the same
fakefile = BytesIO(my_encoded_c_struct)
my_c_structure = MyCStructure()
fakefile.readinto(my_c_structure)
```

Pickle and the like are not necessary. Neither is [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.pack) though it would work. It's just more complicated.

Edit: also see the linked answer at [How to pack and unpack using ctypes (Structure <-> str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825715/how-to-pack-and-unpack-using-ctypes-structure-str/1827666#1827666) for another method for doing this.

Edit 2: See http://doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/struct or http://effbot.org/librarybook/struct.htm for struct examples.

Comment: See http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/struct/ or http://effbot.org/librarybook/struct.htm for `struct` examples.