# Read or construct an array from a binary file containing both integers and doubles in Python/NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binaryfiles

I have a binary file that contains both integers and doubles. I want to access that data either in one call (something like: `x = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int)`) or sequentially (value by value). However, NumPy doesn't seem to allow to read from a binary file without specifying a type. Should I convert everything to double, or forget about NumPy?

Edit. Let's say the format of the file is something like this:

int

int int int double double double double double double double

etc.

Comment: Check out the `struct` module.

Comment: Why can't you read value-by-value, assuming you know the format of the  file and thus know which is an integer and which a double, then fill the numpy array with the promoted type (e.g. all float)?

Comment: "I have a binary file that contains both integers and doubles" - what is the format of this binary file? "Binary file" is not enough information to tell how this data is represented; without more information, we cannot tell how to read this file.

Comment: This example might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215715/reading-a-binary-file-into-a-struct-in-python

Comment: If you want help with your specific example, consider posting a short example of the file, and what you want as output :) Also see [mcve].

Comment: Is the sequence of numeric types predictable? Periodic? Is there a header? If it's just "binary", how can you know what the _next_ type is, while sequentially reading the values? Also, notice that only because the fractional part of a number is zero (eg. `10.000`) that doesn't necessarily means it's an integer.

Comment: Okay, your edit is marginally better, but you seem to be expecting a "binary file" to work like writing on a piece of paper, with spaces between numbers, and lines, and all sorts of other formatting and disambiguation built in. There's just a sequence of bytes. You can't even write an *int* to a file without specifying a representation, and you can't read one without knowing the representation either. Unless you build in some sort of disambiguation yourself, you can't tell whether 8 bytes are one 64-bit float or 2 32-bit integers or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumPy doesn't seem to allow to read from a binary file without specifying a type
```

No programming language I know of pretends to be able to guess the type of raw binary data; and for good reasons. What exactly is the higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd need numpy for this. The basic Python binary library `struct` is doing the job. Convert list of tuples given at end into numpy array if so desired.

For sources see https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html and @martineau
[Reading a binary file into a struct in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215715/reading-a-binary-file-into-a-struct-in-python)

```
from struct import pack,unpack

with open("foo.bin","wb") as file:
    a=pack("<iiifffffff", 1,2,3, 1.1,2.2e-2,3.3e-3,4.4e-4,5.5e-5,6.6e-6,7.7e-7 )
    file.write(a)

with open("foo.bin","r") as file:
    a=unpack("<iiifffffff",file.read() )
    print a
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 1.100000023841858, 0.02199999988079071, 0.0032999999821186066, 0.0004400000034365803, 5.500000042957254e-05, 6.599999778700294e-06, 7.699999855503847e-07)
```

Showing the binary file in a binary editor (Frhed):

[image]

```
#how to read same structure repeatedly
import struct

fn="foo2.bin"
struct_fmt = '<iiifffffff' 
struct_len = struct.calcsize(struct_fmt)
struct_unpack = struct.Struct(struct_fmt).unpack_from

with open(fn,"wb") as file:
    a=struct.pack("<iiifffffff", 1,2,3, 1.1,2.2e-2,3.3e-3,4.4e-4,5.5e-5,6.6e-6,7.7e-7 )
    for i in range(3): 
        file.write(a)


results = []
with open(fn, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(struct_len)
        if not data: break
        s = struct_unpack(data)
        results.append(s)

print results
```

output:

```
 [(1, 2, 3, 1.100000023841858, 0.02199999988079071, 0.0032999999821186066, 0.0004400000034365803, 5.500000042957254e-05, 6.599999778700294e-06, 7.699999855503847e-07), (1, 2, 3, 1.100000023841858, 0.02199999988079071, 0.0032999999821186066, 0.0004400000034365803, 5.500000042957254e-05, 6.599999778700294e-06, 7.699999855503847e-07), (1, 2, 3, 1.100000023841858, 0.02199999988079071, 0.0032999999821186066, 0.0004400000034365803, 5.500000042957254e-05, 6.599999778700294e-06, 7.699999855503847e-07)]
```