# Read binary file into struct (translating instructions)

Tags: python, struct, binary

Reading binary files and structs are a new area for me.

I understand how to read in the file and attempted various methods to read the raw data but seems I need to use struct.

I am trying to translate these instructions to python code:

> The beginning of the Binary Merge file contains an array of GWI_file_header_struct structs (defined in file INET_INT.H) for the various channels, followed by the interlaced 32bit floating point data. The 1st 4 bytes in the header is the length of the header for 1 channel in bytes (i.e. 516 = 0x0204). To read the # of channels stored in the file, read the 'channelsPerFile' field of the 1st struct (e.g. to see how many headers are there). After the header, the data is saved in an interlaced form, where points are stored in the order that they are acquired in time.

The main confusion is how do I translate this to:

```
struct.unpack(...)
```

INET_INT.H struct:

```
typedef struct GWI_file_header_struct{  //  This struct is at the beginning of GWI iNet BINARY files that contain waves.
                                    //
                                    //  Macintosh:
                                    //
                                    //      file type:      'GWID'
                                    //      creator type:   'ioNe'      NETWORK_DATA_CREATOR   
    
                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  HEADER INFORMATION
    
iNetINT32 headerSizeInBytes;        //  contains length, in bytes, of this header (this does not include any data) { bytes 0..3, base 0 }

                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  FILE INFORMATION
    
iNetINT32 int32key;                 //  32bit key that should contain 0x12345678 (this will help you make sure your byte lanes are ok). 
                                    //  { bytes 4..7, base 0 }

iNetINT32 file_endian;              //  endian mode of stored data on disk: 0 = bigEndian_ion, 1 = littleEndian_ion
                                    //  { bytes 8..11, base 0 }

iNetINT16 int16key;                 //  16bit key that should contain 0x55b4; (this field should consume 2 bytes
                                    //   in the struct -- no padding) (i.e. INET_INT16_KEY = 0x55b4)
                                    //  { bytes 12..13, base 0 }

iNetINT16 zero;                     //  set to 0 (this field should consume 2 bytes in the struct -- no padding)
                                    //  { bytes 14..15, base 0 }

                                    //  # of seconds since Jan 1, Midnight, 1904 that the acquisition started (this is used to compute the
                                    //  date of acquisition). This overflows in 2030.
                                    //  Strip Chart: 1st digitized point in entire stream (i.e. 1st pt of 1st scan)
                                    //  Osc Mode:    1st point in current scan, secsSince1904_Int64 units 
                                    //  { bytes 16..19, base 0 }
iNetUINT32 acquisition_SecsSince1904_FixedUint32_OverflowIn2030;
                                    
                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  # OF POINTS STORED
                                    //
                                    //  This file contains a set of scans.  Each scan is 1 to .5billion points long.  For example,
                                    //  we might have 100 scans, each 1000 points long. In this example:
                                    //
                                    //      pointsPerScanThisChannel_LSW = 1000
                                    //      pointsPerScanThisChannel_MSW = 0
                                    //
                                    //      numScansStoredBeforeLastScan = 99
                                    //
                                    //      numPointsInLastPartialScan_LSW = 1000
                                    //      numPointsInLastPartialScan_MSW = 0
                                    //
                                    //  Each channel can have a different number of points per scan due to the sampleRateChanMULTiplier

iNetUINT32 pointsPerScanThisChannel_LSW;    
iNetUINT32 pointsPerScanThisChannel_MSW;    
                                    //  # points per scan =  (pointsPerScanThisChannel_MSW * 2^32) + pointsPerScanThisChannel_LSW
                                    //  { bytes 20..23, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 24..27, base 0 }

iNetUINT32 numScansStoredBeforeLastScan_LSW;            
                                    //  # of complete scans stored in file 
                                    //  { bytes 28..31, base 0 }

//  iNetUINT32 numScansStoredBeforeLastScan_MSW;    
                                    //  this is defined below, at the end of the struct

iNetUINT32 numPointsInLastPartialScan_LSW;  
iNetUINT32 numPointsInLastPartialScan_MSW;  
                                    //  # points stored in last scan if it is partially complete = (numPointsInLastPartialScan_MSW * 2^32) + numPointsInLastPartialScan_LSW
                                    //  { bytes 32..35, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 36..39, base 0 }

                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  TIME INFORMATION

iNetFLT32 firstPoint_Time_Secs;     //  time of 1st point, units are seconds
                                    //  { bytes 40..43, base 0 }

iNetFLT32 endUser_channel_samplePeriod_Secs;
                                    //  time between points for this channel,
                                    //  units are seconds.  Notice that channels
                                    //  can have different sample rates, which
                                    //  is the master_endUser_SampleRate / sampleRate_Divider,
                                    //  where 'sampleRate_Divider' is an integer.
                                    //  { bytes 44..47, base 0 }

                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  TYPE OF DATA STORED

iNetINT32 arrayDataType;            //  Type of src array data. iNetDataType:
                                    //
                                    //  0   iNetDT_INT16:   16bit integer, signed
                                    //  2   iNetDT_UINT16:  16bit integer, unsigned
                                    //  3   iNetDT_INT32:   32bit integer, signed
                                    //  4   iNetDT_UINT32:  32bit integer, unsigned
                                    //  5   iNetDT_FLT32:   32bit float (IEEE flt32 format)
                                    //  6   iNetDT_Double:  'double', as determined by the compiler
                                    //                      (e.g. flt64, flt80, flt96, flt128)
                                    //                      see 'bytesPerDataPoint' field to see
                                    //                      how many bytes
                                    //  { bytes 48..51, base 0 }
                                            
iNetINT32 bytesPerDataPoint;        //  # of bytes for each datapoint (e.g. 4 for 32bit signed integer)
                                    //  { bytes 52..55, base 0 }

iNetStr31 verticalUnitsLabel;       //  pascal string of vertical units label (e.g. "Volts")
                                    //  { bytes 56..87, base 0 }

iNetStr31 horizontalUnitsLabel;     //  horizontal units label, e.g. "Secs", pascal string (0th char is the # of valid chars)   
                                    //  { bytes 88..119, base 0 }

iNetStr31 userName;                 //  user named set by user, e.g. "Pressure 1" , pascal string (0th char is the # of valid chars)   
                                    //  { bytes 120..151, base 0 }

iNetStr31 chanName;                 //  name of channel, e.g. "Ch1 Vin+", pascal string (0th char is the # of valid chars)   
                                    //  { bytes 152..183, base 0 }

                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  DATA MAPPING
                                    //
iNetINT32 minCode;                  //  if data is stored in integer format, this contains the mapping from integer 
iNetINT32 maxCode;                  //  to engineering units (e.g. +/-2048 A/D data is mapped to +/- 10V, minCode = -2048,
iNetFLT32 minEU;                    //  maxCode = +2047, minEU = -10.000, maxEU = +9.995.
iNetFLT32 maxEU;                    //  
                                    //  { bytes 184..187, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 188..191, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 192..195, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 196..199, base 0 }

                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  iNet NETWORK ADDRESS (this does not need
                                    //  to be filled in, 0L's are ok)

iNetINT32 netNum;                   //  channel network # (this pertains to iNet only; use 0 otherwise)
                                    //  { bytes 200..203, base 0 }

iNetINT32 devNum;                   //  channel device # (this pertains to iNet only; use 0 otherwise)
                                    //  { bytes 204..207, base 0 }

iNetINT32 modNum;                   //  channel module # (this pertains to iNet only; use 0 otherwise)
                                    //  { bytes 208..211, base 0 }

iNetINT32 chNum;                    //  channel channel # (this pertains to iNet only; use 0 otherwise)
                                    //  { bytes 212..215, base 0 }
        
                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  END USER NOTES

iNetStr255 notes;                   //  pascal string that contains notes about the data stored.
                                    //  { bytes 216..471, base 0 }

                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  MAPPING

iNetFLT32 /* must remain flt32 */ internal1;    //  Mapping from internal engineering units (e.g. Volts) to external engineering                     
iNetFLT32 /* must remain flt32 */ external1;    //  units (e.g. mmHg).  This is used for 2 point linear mapping/calibration to  
iNetFLT32 /* must remain flt32 */ internal2;    //  a new, user defined, coordinate system.  instruNet World does not read these values
iNetFLT32 /* must remain flt32 */ external2;    //  from the wave files, yet instead reads them from the instrNet.prf file -- they
                                    //  are only stored for the benefit of other software that might read this file. gsw 12/1/96
                                    //  { bytes 472..475, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 476..479, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 480..483, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 484..487, base 0 }

iNetFLT32 flt32key;                 //  flt32 key set to 1234.56 (i.e. INET_FLT32_KEY), Used to test floating point code. gsw 12/1/96
                                    //  { bytes 488..491, base 0 }

iNetINT32 sampleRate_Divider;       //  this channel is digitized at the master_endUser_SampleRate divided 
                                    //  this 'sampleRate_Divider' (i.e. sampleRateChanMULT_integerRatio_N_int64)
                                    //  (helpful with FileType Binary Merge), gsw 1/29/97. Note: This field was introduced 1/29/97 and
                                    //  files saved before that time set it to 0.
                                    //  { bytes 492..495, base 0 }
                                    
iNetINT32 channelsPerFile;          //  # of channels per file (i.e. interlaced after array of headers) (helpful with FileType Binary Merge), gsw 1/29/97
                                    //  Note: This field was introduced 1/29/97 and files saved before that time set it to 0.
                                    //  { bytes 496..499, base 0 }
                                    
                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  EXPANSION FIELDS

                                    #if 1   //  gsw 12/23/09

                                    //  # of complete scans stored in file, MS 32bits
                                    //  { bytes 500..503, base 0 }
iNetUINT32 numScansStoredBeforeLastScan_MSW;    

                                    #else
                                    iNetINT32 expansion8;               //  expansion fields that are preset to 
                                    #endif

iNetINT32 expansion9;               //  0 and then ignored
iNetINT32 expansion10;              //  { bytes 500..503, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 504..507, base 0 }
                                    //  { bytes 508..511, base 0 }

                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  KEY TO TEST STRUCT PACKING

iNetINT32 int32key_StructTest;      //  32bit key that should contain 0x12345678; (i.e. INET_INT32_KEY)
                                    //  { bytes 512..515, base 0 }
                                    
                                    //  ----------------------------------
                                    //  ACTUAL DATA

/* iNetFLT32 *data[1]; */           //  contains array of data of type 'arrayDataType'

} GWI_file_header_struct;
```

**Final Code and Results:**

*Code*

```
from struct import *
# Current 3 channels: Ch11 Vin+, Ch13 Vin+ and Ch15 Vin+
# Header info extracted using provided header struct (INET_INT.H)
# After the header, the data is saved in an interlaced form,
# where points are stored in the order that they are acquired in time.
# 3 channels: A[0], B[0], C[0], A[1], B[1], C[1]...
# After header = 516 header size x 3 channels = 1,548 bytes
# Start of data at 1,548 bytes?
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(12)
    header_size, int32key, file_endian = unpack('<3i', byte)
    # channel name 1
    f.seek(152)
    chan = f.read(183-152)
    chan = struct.unpack("<31s", chan)[0].rstrip(b'\x00').lstrip(b'\t')
    # channel name 2
    f.seek(152+header_size)
    chan2 = f.read(183-152)
    chan2 = struct.unpack("<31s", chan2)[0].rstrip(b'\x00').lstrip(b'\t')
print(header_size, int32key, file_endian)
print("channel 1: {}".format(chan))
print("channel 2: {}".format(chan2))
```

*Results*

```
516 305419896 1
channel 1: b'Ch11 Vin+'
channel 2: b'Ch13 Vin+'
```

Comment: There's some inforrmation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215715/reading-a-binary-file-into-a-struct) that might help but you'll probably want to read the documentation for ```struct``` in more detail.

Comment: Things are not as complicated as they may seem, **if** you can read and understand the `struct` definition in "INET_INT.H", although this file format has a special quirk with those interlaced channel values. But you will need to post the content of that .h file if you want some help in translating it as a first step

Comment: @gimix thank you for the starting point. I was able to locate the INET_INT.H file and edited my post to include the portion that seems to relate to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is not a full answer but I feel comments would be really unreadable here.

The first step is reading the first 12 bytes (three 4-bytes integers), and unpack them so we can check the endianness. Let's try big-endian first

```
from struct import *
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(12)
header_size, int32key, file_endian = unpack('>3i', byte)
```

We expect to have `int32key` set at 305419896 (= \x12345678). If we get another value then let's switch to little-endian, i.e. change our unpack format string to `<3i`.

At this point we can read the rest of the header, with the same logic, and get all the info we need to read data for the first channel. I hope this can be a good start for you.

Comment: this was very helpful, I was able to receive header_size, int32key, file_endian = 516 305419896 1 using little-endian unpack('<3i', byte). From here I was able to extract other header information. Number of channels, channel names. etc. The next portion I would need help with is the "data stored in interlace form, A[0], B[0], etc. Would this data be after the header and translated the same way? Ill update my post to show where I am and details.

Comment: The channel data surely are right after the header. They are an array of data of the type specified by the ArrayDataType header field. Beware that you may need to convert them as explained in the "DATA MAPPING" section

Comment: Got it, this answers my question and updated in my post. @gimix thank you so much for the help!