# Structure vs unpack

Tags: python

When should someone use *ctypes.Structure* and when should someone use *struct.unpack*?

In general, I use *ctypes.Structure* when I want to extract data from an embedded device that runs C.
I would first extract the raw binary data from my embedded device and then use a *cytpes.Structure* that describes it. Using the structure I then have my data in the correct form.

Is using *struct.unpack* and *ctypes.Structure* equivalent?

Comment: Im wondering are there any downfalls for using it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Similar functionality in struct and array vs ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004279/python-similar-functionality-in-struct-and-array-vs-ctypes)